# Android Layout, messed up LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

```
  <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_width="200dp" android:paddingTop="30dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:layout_height="250dp">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="30dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonEasy" android:text="Easy"></Button>
        <Button android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="30dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Medium" android:id="@+id/buttonMed"></Button>
        <Button android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="30dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonHard" android:text="Hard"></Button>
        <Button android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="30dp" android:textColor="#f45b3c" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Custom" android:id="@+id/buttonCustom"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayoutProblem"></LinearLayout>
```

This is my Layout, the "@+id/linearLayoutProblem" Is appearing on the right side. like so,
http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/8821/helpbottom.jpg

I want "@+id/linearLayoutProblem" to appear on the bottom. How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What root layout are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping all of that in another `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` like so?

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_width="200dp" android:paddingTop="30dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:layout_height="250dp">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="30dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonEasy" android:text="Easy"></Button>
        <Button android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="30dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Medium" android:id="@+id/buttonMed"></Button>
        <Button android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="30dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonHard" android:text="Hard"></Button>
        <Button android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="30dp" android:textColor="#f45b3c" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Custom" android:id="@+id/buttonCustom"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayoutProblem"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have better results with a RelativeLayout - look into `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check out what it is about. :)